# MySQL DATE_FORMAT using BETWEEN doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I'm using two stored functions, They work and when put into SELECT, they return proper values, however when i try to reduce and get a subset of those values, I get an empty set with no warnings.

Here's my SQL.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    e.ims_event_id,
    e.name,
    e.begin_time bUTC,
    e.end_time eUTC,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(e.begin_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, e.begin_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i') begin_local,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(e.end_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, e.end_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i') end_local,
    DATE_FORMAT(ptat_getEventHalfPoint(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, e.begin_time, e.duration, country),'%H:%i') begin_local_halfPoint,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(pp.start_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, pp.start_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i') ptat_begin,
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(pp.end_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, pp.end_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i') ptat_end 
FROM
    event e
    JOIN service s ON e.service_uid = s.service_uid
    JOIN service_ptc sp ON s.service_uid = sp.service_uid
    JOIN service_primetime_period spp ON s.service_uid = spp.service_uid
    JOIN primetime_period pp ON spp.primetime_period_uid = pp.primetime_period_uid
    JOIN time_zone tz ON pp.time_zone_id = tz.time_zone_id 
    JOIN dlst_info dli ON country = 'US' AND dli.year = DATE_FORMAT(e.begin_time,'%Y')
WHERE
    (POW(2,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(e.begin_time,INTERVAL tz.delta_time HOUR), '%w'))&pp.weekdays) > 0 AND
    e.end_time > NOW() AND 
    e.begin_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 8 DAY) AND
    DATE_FORMAT(ptat_getEventHalfPoint(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, e.begin_time, e.duration, country),'%H:%i') BETWEEN
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(pp.start_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, pp.start_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i') AND
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(pp.end_time, INTERVAL ptat_getTZOffset(pp.subject_to_dlst, tz.delta_time, pp.end_time, country) MINUTE),'%H:%i')
ORDER BY e.begin_time;
```

The last 3 lines of the WHERE clause when added, return zero. They are copy and pasted in to SELECT and work just fine.

I'm absolutely baffled!

Also, when using a string for comparison (i.e. ... =  '19:00'), I get results. Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Edit: Sample Rows returned when not including the where clause.

```
|    370617336 | Dancing With the Stars             | 2012-04-04 05:00:00 | 2012-04-04 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371138764 | Escape Routes                      | 2012-04-08 05:00:00 | 2012-04-08 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371138733 | Who Do You Think You Are?          | 2012-04-07 05:00:00 | 2012-04-07 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371138638 | The Biggest Loser                  | 2012-04-04 05:00:00 | 2012-04-04 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371676424 | Survivor: One World                | 2012-04-05 05:00:00 | 2012-04-05 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371676489 | Undercover Boss                    | 2012-04-07 05:00:00 | 2012-04-07 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371676386 | NCIS                               | 2012-04-04 05:00:00 | 2012-04-04 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371412875 | Bones                              | 2012-04-03 05:00:00 | 2012-04-03 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371413006 | American Idol                      | 2012-04-06 05:00:00 | 2012-04-06 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371413149 | Bones                              | 2012-04-10 05:00:00 | 2012-04-10 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    371413041 | The Finder                         | 2012-04-07 05:00:00 | 2012-04-07 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 19:00      | 22:00    |
|    370617100 | Once Upon a Time                   | 2012-04-09 05:00:00 | 2012-04-09 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 18:00      | 22:00    |
|    371138792 | Harry's Law                        | 2012-04-09 05:00:00 | 2012-04-09 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 18:00      | 22:00    |
|    371676549 | The Amazing Race                   | 2012-04-09 05:00:00 | 2012-04-09 06:00:00 | 19:00       | 20:00     | 19:30                 | 18:00      | 22:00    |
```

EDIT #2: 
I took all the fields from all the tables and combined it into one table in a sandbox. I made both my functions static (to always assume we're in summer daylight savings season) and added sample data. IT WORKS! So I have to backtrack I guess and it's nothing that's wrong with the SQL syntax or logic. Some column, some join or table is failing. Also I intermittently get this error:

```
Error | 1366 | Incorrect decimal value: '' for column '' at row -1
```

If I could attach an SQL file, i could attach my test schema, I don't want to paste it here.

Comment: Can you show us a sample row that is returned if you don't include these 3 lines in the WHERE clause?

Comment: So clarification on what i'm looking for. If you look at sample day. I'm looking for rows where the eventHalfPoint (7th column) falls between the 8th and last. So All of these rows should be returned. 19:30 is between 19:00 and 22:00 (and between 18:00 and 22:00, see last 3 rows).

Comment: Do these rows get returned when you have the first 3 coditions included in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Yes. Only the last 3 lines of the clause make it return empty results.

Comment: OK. If you confirm that the sample you have given is returned by a query that includes the `WHERE (POW(2,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(e.begin_time,INTERVAL tz.delta_time HOUR), '%w'))&pp.weekdays) > 0 AND e.end_time > NOW() AND e.begin_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 8 DAY)`, then this is baffling for me, too.

Comment: Yep, in fact the sample size is from a copy and paste of that query minus the DATE_FORMAT() clauses.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9616/discussion-between-ypercube-and-dlite922)

Answer (score 1):

I also found a little while doing my project stuff.

Wanted to filter records from DB , which are between 5 AM to 1 PM.
I want to pass , AM or PM parameter in query string.
But mysql date_format always take 24 hours format. AM or PM doesn't matter.

```
select  poll_voting_result_id,poll_master_id,date_voting,date_format(date_voting,'%Y-%m-%d %r') as 12_hour_format_R,
date_format(date_voting,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %p') as 24_hour_format_P from poll_voting_result 
where up_down = 0 
and 
poll_master_id = '11' 
and 
date(date_voting) = '2013-03-20' 
and date_format(date_voting,'%H:%i:%s %r') BETWEEN '05:00 AM' and '13:01:06 PM' 
order by date_voting ASC


select  poll_voting_result_id,poll_master_id,date_voting,date_format(date_voting,'%Y-%m-%d %r') as 12_hour_format_R,
date_format(date_voting,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s %p') as 24_hour_format_P from poll_voting_result 
where up_down = 0 
and 
poll_master_id = '11' 
and 
date(date_voting) = '2013-03-20' 
and date_format(date_voting,'%H:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN '05:00' and '13:01:06' 
order by date_voting ASC
```

Above Both query working fine.
But i need to pass

BETWEEN '05:00 AM' and '01:01:06 PM'